# Ubuntu 21.04 freezes in dell inspiron 15-3000

Tags: dual-boot, dell, 21.04, inspiron

I am experiencing random screen freezes too often while working on ubuntu 21.04 in dell Inspiron 15-3000. The system came with a Windows 10 OS, and I dual boot it myself and is currently having Ubuntu alongwith Windows OS. Windows work pretty well. But ubuntu freezes quite often, like 6-7 times in 1 hour. The mouse, touchpad, or keyboard doesnt work and i have to reboot the system using the power button.

Sometimes, it may restart itself after a freeze. I am new to ubuntu, please help me solve the issue.

Comment: Before anything else: Update UEFI.

Comment: Please help me to update UEFI. What should I do?

Comment: Search Dell's website for drivers and "BIOS", download a follow instructions.